# How to add textview programmatically from JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

I have create my Activity from my json file.

Now i try to put a TextView in my new Activity but it doesn't.

Here is my json file :

```
"interface":{
"View":[
{
    "id":"0",
    "type":"Simple",
    "Label":[
        {
    "text":"bonjour comment ca va ?",
    "position_x":"200",
        "position_y":"400"
        },
        {
        "text":"coucou les amis",
        "position_x":"200",
        "position_y":"200"
        }
    ],
```

etc

My Activity works well.

public class ClassicView extends Activity {

```
public int myid;


public ClassicView() {

}
     public ClassicView(int id){
         super();
         myid = id;
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linearlayout);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));           
        setContentView(ll);
    }
}
```

I get my View with his id from json. But i don't know how to put my textview in my View.

Here is my code :

```
public ClassicView getClassicViewWithId(int id) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray myView = myjsonobj.getJSONObject("interface").getJSONArray("View");           
        for (int i = 0; i < myView.length(); i++) {
            if (myView.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id") == id) {
                Log.e("IDVIEW", myView.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                ClassicView myClassicView = new ClassicView(myView.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));

                classicSetLabel(myView.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Label"), myClassicView);
                return myClassicView;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void classicSetLabel(JSONArray myArrayLabel, ClassicView classicView) throws JSONException {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTLABEL :", "classicSetLabelErreur1");



        Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTLABEL :", "classicSetLabelErreur2");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArrayLabel.length(); i++) {
            Log.e("CLASSICVIEW", classicView.toString());
            TextView myTextView = new TextView(classicView);
            myTextView.append(myArrayLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
            classicView.addContentView(myTextView, params);
            Log.e("@@@@@WARNING TEXTLABEL :", myArrayLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
        }
```

}

My MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    JSONParser jParser = null;
    try {
        jParser = new JSONParser("JsonTest.txt");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ClassicView view = jParser.getClassicViewWithId(0);
        //Log.e("idVIEWMAIN :", msg)
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, view.getClass());
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i try to instanciate my Textview, my LogCat say java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by : at com.fchps.bya.json.JSONParser.classicSetLabel(JSONParser.java:89)

Line 89 = TextView myTextView = new TextView(classicView);

So who can explain to me what's my error. I tried for 1 week and it doesn't work so i come here to know if somoby could help me please :)

I can't add my TextView to my view with : `Why :

```
classicView.setContentView(myTextView);
```

doesn't work ? I already have my LinearLayout in my classicview class.`

Thanks :)

Comment: method `classicSetLabel` is inside which `activity` or is it separate class?

Comment: classicSetLabel is in my JSONParser class not inside which activity. But my ClassicView herite from Activity

Comment: `ClassicView` inheriting from activity will not help you in any way. You need the context of the running activity or application context. Creating a new _activity_ object and passing it like that will not work

Comment: How can I get the context of my ClassicView ? I don't understand

Comment: TextView myTextView =new TextView(classicView.getApplicationContext()); Doesn't work

Comment: @user2871328 : where you are calling getClassicViewWithId method?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK in my MainActivity :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for creating View in java class you will need Activity Context. add one more context parameter to  getClassicViewWithId method as:

```
public ClassicView getClassicViewWithId(int id,Context context) 
                                                throws JSONException {

     classicSetLabel(myView.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Label"),
                                                myClassicView,context);
        return null;
  }

 public void classicSetLabel(JSONArray myArrayLabel, ClassicView classicView,
                                      Context context) throws JSONException {

        for (int i = 0; i < myArrayLabel.length(); i++) {
            Log.e("CLASSICVIEW", classicView.toString());
            TextView myTextView = new TextView(context);

        }
}
```

now pass Activity Context to `getClassicViewWithId` method from Activity with id:

```
ClassicView view = jParser.getClassicViewWithId(your_id,MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Ok but i don't to define this context you declare ?

Comment: @user2871328 : no need to define Context just add parameters to both method and pass it from Activity using `MainActivity.this` same as im doing in answer

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK This will work fine.. what happens in the next line? `classicView.addContentView(myTextView, params);` will the textView become visible?

Comment: @user2871328 : to make TextView Visible you will need to add all TextViews to Current Activity Layout

Comment: Yes but I don't know how many TextView i have because the number is reading in json file. It can be 4 textviews, or 10 textview. It depend of the application user.. I know how to set 1 or 2 textview programmaticaly but not X TextView..

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Why classicView.setContentView(myTextView);
doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(classicView);
```

You need the activity context here:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(YourActivityName.this);
```

or

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: It doesn't worked with getApplicationContext(). When i tried new TextView(ClassicView.this). It doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

If you want add TextView vertically and dynamically, then try to use ListView.

Comment: I want to create Object programmatically from my json file. I have View. Now i tried to put Element in my View.